# Android Loading Indicator for Downloading Images

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using an Image Loaded which loads images based on requirment and since the images are big. I want to display an intermediate Spinning Image showing which would convey that the image is loading to the User.

I am displaying these images in the Viewpager.

We can not use a Gif image to display the animation and i wonder how it can be done.

P.S i am not looking for a Progress Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) on the ImageView. Rotate is one of the included animations, and you can define it in XML.

Here's a [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_UWXqFBF86U) from Google explaining it a little more.

Comment: i can just sent an image and use the rotate xml from the res/anim and make it rotate ?

Comment: how do i do it if i have a series of different images is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: You can rotate a single view using ViewAnimation. Or you can apply it to multiple views at once.